# When can an embedded Markov chain X for a Markov process Y be reducible?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

It's pretty widely documented that a Markov process Y is reducible/irreducible if and only if the embedded Markov chain X is reducible/irreducible.

However I'm not sure this works in reverse. I'm wondering if it's possible to determine the converse without actually calculating the embedded Markov chain: i.e. given the generator matrix for a Markov process Y (and its stationary distribution), is it possible to determine from these facts alone whether an embedded Markov chain X for Y is reducible?

In my example I have for Y my generator matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    -3       & 1 & 2  \\
    1       & -2 & 1  \\
    1       & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}

and hence the stationary distribution: $\pi = (1/4, 1/8, 5/8) $

Comment: Reverse of what? Stationary distributions? These are offtopic. In your case, the embedded Markov chain has probability transition matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
    0     & 1/3 & 2/3  \\
    1/2       & 0 & 1/2  \\
    1       & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},$$ which is obviously irreducible. Note that only the nondiagonal places in the generator matrix with nonzero entries are relevant.

Comment: I mean: does an irreducible (determined using the generator matrix) Markov process imply the embedded Markov chain is also irreducible?
In retrospect this would've been a much clearer wording.

Comment: The sequences of visited states are the same for both proceses hence I still fail to understand the question.